# TPMs available on mobile with application access

Tags: mobile, hardware, tpm

I am looking for a mobile device, preferably a smartphone or a tablet, that contains a TPM (v1.2 or 2.0) and provides application access to it through an API.
Does anyone know if any such devices exist?

Comment: I'm not aware of any devices that have a TPM in their hardware design yet.  I'm sure the day is coming though.

Comment: You can try the [secure element](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does any tablet support remote attestation?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24220/does-any-tablet-support-remote-attestation)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only devices that have this are intel laptops-turned-tables. The only example that come to my mind are Surface Pro range. The Surface pro 1 and 2 have a TPM v1.2, and the Surface Pro 3 has a TPM v3.

I don't know of any ARM powered device which has a TPM (although I think there's work in progress on this). In ARM, there's also a security feature called [TrustZone](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/index.php), it might be good if you check that, as it might provide enough features to do whatever you need. For what I know this solution includes a security module called SecurCore where all the sensitive operations are performed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, HocusPocus. I'm aware of TrustZone. Do you know if ARM smartphones today have TrustZone enabled?

Comment: I'm not really into mobiles, but the module is inside the Cortex cores mobile use... Also doing a quick check it looks like some Samsung mobiles and a few other vendors already use this feature.